# How to send Junit test results to InfluxDB

Tags: reporting, junit5, influxdb

Currently, I've some tests suite in place with me using Junit 5. Wanted to send the test result metrics to Grafana. I'm thinking of sending the test results to Influx db and re-route it to Grafana at the end. Is there a way to use Sunfire XML file to achieve this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I am planning to do the same, and I found this on the web.

https://medium.com/detesters/how-to-store-junit-tests-in-an-influxdb-7faf63dd562a

I will do more research and am thinking of creating a junit5 extension to do this. If I have a solution, I will post it here.